# android: firebase authentication via phone number automatically authenticates

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

The recently added phone authentication in firebase authenticates has two types of users on successful authentication as provided in the documentation:

> Instant verification: in some cases the phone number can be instantly verified without needing to send or enter a verification code.
>
> Auto-retrieval: on some devices, Google Play services can automatically detect the incoming verification SMS and perform verification without user action.

But I would like to authenticate the users on the basis of sending SMS instead. So how could it be resolved. And how can it be determined how the users are getting authenticated. Also in some cases if the user is already authenticated in some other device it automatically gets authenticated in some other device without sending the SMS on either of the devices.

Any help would be appreciated.